# How to host two web applications with different "domains" in IIS 8

Tags: iis-8, asp.net-mvc, hosts, windows-8, bindings

I have setup to entries in my hosts file:

> 127.0.0.1 mymvcapp.dev www.mymvcapp.dev
>
> 127.0.0.1 mywebapi.dev www.mywebapi.dev

In the first I want to host my mvc app and the second entry is for my web api app.
Now I have added these two bindings to my IIS8, so all in all 4 bindings one with www and one without for each application in the default website in IIS.

The problem is when I try to access any of these urls above, they point me to the mvc application.
Now in VS I try to change the virtual directory for the WebAPI project, but this also changes the bidning of my mvc app. When I do this, now I can connect to my web api, but when I use the mvc app url I get the web api.

How to configure this right?

[image: Web api project in VS]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the "mywebapi.dev" bindings from the default website.
Added a new website beside the default website with the mentioned http/https bindings.
Not sure if this is necessary.
Added a new application whose physical path maps to my web api project folder.
In the project properties -> Web tab I choose IIS and entered the project url:

> https://www.mywebapi.dev

And entries in the hosts file are needed for each website:

> 127.0.0.1     mymvcapp.dev
>
> 127.0.0.1     www.mymvcapp.dev
>
> 127.0.0.1     mywebapi.dev
>
> 127.0.0.1     www.mywebapi.dev

In the respective website you need a binding for both hostnames.
One with and the other without "www"!

That's it.